Workaraound Greasepencil visuals being limited to look good in standard view transform only
In this scene I have 3d elements and 2d greasepencil arrows and handwriting which should be looking well saturated and punchy, yet in rendered view it's desaturated due to filmic transform


If i set it to standard view transform it comes out alright but the rest of the scene looks bad.
I want the greasepencil elements to render in standard view transform and the rest of the scene in filmic

You could separate your render in 2 view layers, then in compositing apply a Convert Colorspace to the grease pencil. Is there something preventing you from doing that ?

just in case, have you unchecked "Use Lights" on the GP layer?

@pevinkinel yes I've done that , you can see that in the image I've provided

@Lutzi ok , thanks I didn't know that

@PranjalRathor my bad, I meant at the layer level cos I didn't even know you could switch it off at object level (such a time saver! cheers)
